# How to pick one username:password every 3 proxy in bash?

Tags: bash, proxy

I have bash script that need proxy to running because it's a curl script, the problem is every 3 proxy has a different username and password. I have managed by curl script to have random proxy and proxy username:password, but How to manage it pick different username:password after 3 proxy taken , Thanks

The code itself :

```
rand_useragent=$(head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < tmp/ua.lst` + 1)) tmp/ua.lst | tail -1)
rand_proxy=$(head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < tmp/proxy.lst` + 1)) tmp/proxy.lst | tail -1)
rand_user=$(head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < tmp/userproxy.lst` +`)) tmp/userproxy.lst | tail -1)
posted=`curl --max-time 20 --connect-timeout 20 --proxy "$rand_proxy" --user-proxy "$rand_user" 'url'
```